# Cascading Tap Configuration for Amazon S3 to Local file System

Tags: amazon-s3, cascading

So I'm trying out the cascading framework and I was able to run apps in local. As a next step I want to use Cascading to download files from S3 to local file system. I'm planning to use FileTap. When I google I found S3FS and looks like its deprecated. Can someone point me in the right direction. In other words, what is the right way to create a FileTap for Amazon S3 with access id and secret key like stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse is still in active development.

Answer (score 1):

Though this code is for the HadoopFlowConnector this will work with Local Flow connector if using the FileTap.

```
public class Main {
                public void run(String[] args) {
                    Properties properties = new Properties();
                    String accessKey = args[0];
                    String secretKey = args[1];
                    // better put these keys to hadoop xml file
                    // for block file system
                    properties.setProperty("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey);
                    properties.setProperty("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey);
                    // for s3 native file system
                    // properties.setProperty("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey);
                    // properties.setProperty("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey);
                    // properties.setProperty("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020/");
                    // properties.setProperty("fs.permissions.umask-mode", "007");
                    AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Main.class);
                    HadoopFlowConnector flowConnector = new HadoopFlowConnector(
                        properties);
                    String input = "s3://my-bucket/my-log.csv";
                    // If using the native S3
                    // String input = "s3n://my-bucket/my-log.csv";

                    Tap inTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(false, ";"), input);
                    Pipe copyPipe = new Pipe("copy");
                    Tap outTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(false, ";"),
                        "data/output");
                    FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef()
                        .addSource(copyPipe, inTap)
                        .addTailSink(copyPipe, outTap);
                    flowConnector.connect(flowDef).complete();
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    new Main().run(args);
                }
            }
```

Code courtesy http://whiteboxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/01/processing-data-from-aws-s3-using.html.

I just added the S3N string input commented line. Since I was using S3N based accessing I uncommented the S3N features and used it.